# Synonym request: [c++0x] ↔ [c++11]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

C++0x was the [*working name*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) for C++11, but they are still the same thing.  At this time, [c++0x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) is tagged with 4 questions and [c++11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) is tagged with 98 questions.  Although there's no problem retagging those 4 questions, it should still be okay to use either tag.  C++11 just has the most questions because it's the final name of this standard.

This was already done on SO, so it should be correct.  I cannot put in the vote myself since I don't have a sufficient tag score.

Comment: Thanks, @codesparkle!